# Show that $m = x^2 + y^2 \iff p_i\equiv 2 \text{ or } 1 \mod 4$

Tags: number-theory

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $m=a\prod\limits_i p_i$, with $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$
m = x^2 + y^2 \iff p_i\equiv 2 \text{ or } 1 \mod 4
$$

I know that by Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares, $p_i\equiv 1\mod 4$ and $p_i$ is an odd prime if and only if $p_i=x^2+y^2$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Can anyone give me any hints or guide me the right way?

Comment: Note:  $x^2, y^2\equiv 0$ or $1\pmod4$

Comment: What is $a$ or constraint on it? As stated, it is possible that $a =14$ and $p_1 = 7$....

Comment: Chiming in with @achillehui. The claim is false as stated. You might have $m=3^2+0^2$, $a=3$, $p_1=3$.

Comment: I assume it should be $a^2$, not $a$, and with the $p_i$ distinct primes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant to write $a^2$ instead of $a$ (with the $p_i$ distinct primes). This is a very standard result in number theory (you should be able to find it in any textbook) and I don't know how to hint the solution without giving it away, but some lemmas you might find useful include:

1. The product of two sums of squares is also a sum of squares;
2. If $x^2+y^2\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, then $x\equiv y\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

In both cases it is very helpful to think in terms of arithmetic of the Gaussian integers.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a textbook with the proof?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown See e.g. Hardy and Wright chapter XX (which builds on results in earlier chapters).

Comment: Can you actually provide me with a link and where the proof is located?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Numbers-G-Hardy/dp/0199219869

Comment: Do you know of a virtual copy? Where exactly the proof is?

Answer (score 0):

To make sense, I suppose that the hypothesis is $m=a^2\prod_i p_i$. The general criterion (necessary and sufficient condition) for $m=\prod_p p^{v_p(m)}$ to be a sum of squares is the parity of all the exponents $v_p(m)$ for $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$. The proof of course builds on Fermat's theorem, and the clearest way to organize calculations is probably to work in the gaussian ring $\mathbf Z[i]$, see e.g. P. Samuel's booklet "Algebraic Number Theory", 5.6, thm.1. In your case, $a^2$ takes care of the parity requirement, and remains only the condition $p_i \equiv 1$ or $3\pmod 4$.